# Twilio CallResource not posting on busy signal

Tags: twilio

I dial a number using CallResource.Create and specify To, From, Url and MachineDetection=Enable.  I get an event post to the Url I specify most of the time however if the call result is 'busy' (according to the Twilio Console logs), I do not get a post. I need to react no matter the call result, there are other processes in play that are left hanging if I don't get some event notification.

How do I guarantee I get a response; human, machine, busy, fail, etc. no matter the result consistently?

Update: This also happens when the result of a call is 'fail'. We just had that happen. I need to know if a call is answering machine or human (that works) or if the call ends for any other reason like 'busy' or 'fail' or whatever else is out there. How is this supposed to be done if not via the URL call back parameter when making a call?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When a call receives a "busy" signal or fails, the URL in the `url` parameter won't be called.

However, you can get this information by setting up a [`StatusCallback` URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls#statuscallback-parameter). This URL is used to send call progress events over the life of a call, and by default it will send a callback at the end of a call regardless of its outcome. [This will breakdown to](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#request-parameters-call-status) "completed" (a successful call), "busy", "no-answer", "failed" and "canceled" (call canceled via the REST API while still ringing).

Let me know if this helps.